# Mac OS Snow Leopard SSH client freezes

Tags: macos, ssh

Strange thing. I'm trying to connect via ssh with command

```
ssh user@host
```

It asks **correct** password for remote host and then nothing happen. I tried to connect to Ubuntu/FreeBSD servers and always got the same issue. `Ctrl+C` not working here so I must to close terminal window.

Is any way to fix this?

```
# ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

UPDATE:
When I using

```
ssh -vvv user@host
```

after asking the password I got this

```
Password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 16 (len 29 padlen 19 extra_pad 64)
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 10 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/X11R6/bin/xauth -f /tmp/ssh-0Y7GGl2NUf/xauthfile generate /tmp/launch-lLdoTI/org.x:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1200 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I added a `ForwardX11Trusted yes` to my `.ssh/config` file and all works fine. But I can't explain why - so I've put this to comment :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. After removing XQuartz completely, the error was resolved. Deleting XQuartz from Applications did not fully remove it from my system. Running this command will wipe it completely.

Copy and paste this entire command into your terminal to remove XQuartz.

```
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist
sudo rm -rf /opt/X11* /Library/Launch*/org.macosforge.xquartz.* /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app /etc/*paths.d/*XQuartz
sudo pkgutil --forget org.macosforge.xquartz.pkg
```

Comment: oh my gosh, you are my hero.. worked perfectly after failing to connect to my Raspberry Pi, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the -vvv option to ssh; that should let you see at what stage it's failing, which is more of a start than what you've got right now.